# How to only plot data on Google Maps with Search Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-5, geocoding, gmaps4rails

Okay bear with me...I am rather somewhat new.
I am able to search my database and plot the results on a Google Map using Gmaps 4rails, but I can't add to the "info window."  So I decided on using a different search method where I can render a file, but it plots much more then just what I search for.  Basically I need to search my database and plot the results automatically on a Google Maps and then have the data of those objects in the Info window marker.

MY First search method in my Search.html.erb file, that works with plotting, but I can't pass data into the info window due to json errors I suppose.

```
    <div class="container page-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="row">
        <% if @businesses.blank? %>
          <h3>Couldn't find a business with your search criteria</h3>
          <% else %>
            <% @businesses.each do |business| %>
        <div class="mapx">  
  <div id="map" style='width: 350px; height: 250px;'></div>  
</div>  
      <script type="text/javascript">  
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');  
handler.buildMap({ provider: { Zoom: 12}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){  
  markers = handler.addMarkers([  
    {  
      "lat": <%= business.latitude %>,  
      "lng": <%= business.longitude %>,  
      "picture": {  
        "width":  32,  
        "height": 32  
      },  
      "infowindow": "SUJU"
    }  
  ]);  
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);  
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
  handler.getMap().setZoom(19);
});  
</script>
              <div class="span4 box-container">
                <div class="holder">
                  <a class="overlay" href="#" title="property title">
                    <span class="more"></span>
                    <% if business.image_url.present? %>
                      <%= link_to image_tag(business.image_url.to_s), business %>
                    <% else %>
                      <%= link_to image_tag("http://placehold.it/300x190"), business %>
                    <% end %>
                  </a>

    <span class="prop-tag">For Sale</span>
    <div class="prop-info">
      <h3 class="prop-title"><%= link_to business.name, business %></h3>
      <ul class="more-info clearfix">
        <li class="info-label clearfix"><span class="pull-left">Phone:</span>
        <span class="qty pull-right"><%= business.phone %></span></li>
        <li class="info-label clearfix"><span class="pull-left">Location:</span>
        <span class="qty pull-right"><%= business.city.capitalize %>, <%= business.state.upcase %></span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


My second method for the search .html .erb file, where I can pass the info window, but it plots more then my search results, so If I search for four items it will plot 30 since that is my limit for will_paginate.

    <div class="container page-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="row">
        <% if @businesses.blank? %>
          <h3>Couldn't find a business with your search criteria</h3>
          <% else %>
            <% @businesses.each do |business| %>
            <div class="mapx">  
  <div id="map" style='width: 350px; height: 250px;'></div>  
</div>  
      <script type="text/javascript">
      handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
      handler.buildMap({ provider: { Zoom: 12 }, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
      markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @businessz_default.to_json %>);
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
  handler.getMap().setZoom(18);
      }); </script>
              <div class="span4 box-container">
                <div class="holder">
                  <a class="overlay" href="#" title="property title">
                    <span class="more"></span>
                    <% if business.image_url.present? %>
                      <%= link_to image_tag(business.image_url.to_s), business %>
                    <% else %>
                      <%= link_to image_tag("http://placehold.it/300x190"), business %>
                    <% end %>
                  </a>

    <span class="prop-tag">For Sale</span>
    <div class="prop-info">
      <h3 class="prop-title"><%= link_to business.name, business %></h3>
      <ul class="more-info clearfix">
        <li class="info-label clearfix"><span class="pull-left">Phone:</span>
        <span class="qty pull-right"><%= business.phone %></span></li>
        <li class="info-label clearfix"><span class="pull-left">Location:</span>
        <span class="qty pull-right"><%= business.city.capitalize %>, <%= business.state.upcase %></span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
    class BusinessesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_business, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    load_businesses
    @businesses = Business.paginate(page: params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @businesses.to_csv(['name', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'address1', 'address2', 'category1_id', 'category2_id', 'category3_id', 'category1', 'category2', 'category3', 'phone', 'website', 'latitude', 'longitude']) }
    end
   # if params[:search]
  #    @businesses = Business.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
   # else
    #  @businesses = Business.all.order("created_at DESC")
    #end
  end

  def import
    Business.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Businesses imported."
  end


  def new
    @business = Business.new
    #@experience = Experience.new
  end

  def create
    @business = Business.new(business_params)
    #if @business.save
     # flash[:success] = "Business saved!"
      #redirect_to @business
  #  else
   #   flash[:alert] = "Business not saved!"
    #  render 'new'
    #end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @business.save
        format.html { redirect_to @business, notice: 'Business was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @business }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @business.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end

  def show

    load_businessz
    @businessz = Business.paginate(page: params[:page])
    #redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?

    @experiences = Experience.where(business_id: @business)
    @reviews = Review.where(business_id: @business)
    #@experiences = @user.experiences.paginate(page: params[:page])
    #@reviews = @user.reviews.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end


  def search

    #@businessz  = Business.search(params)
    @businesses = Business.search(params)
    load_businessz
  end

  def load_businesses 
   @businesses_default = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(Business.paginate(page: params[:page])) do |plot, marker|  
      marker.lat plot.latitude  
      marker.lng plot.longitude  

      @status = rand(1..4)  
      @battery = rand(10..90)  
      @ip = "192.168."+rand(0..255).to_s+"."+rand(15..250).to_s  
      @connected = rand(50..100)  

      if @status == 1  
        url_alert = "/assets/good.png"
        @status == "Normal"  
      else  
        url_alert = "/assets/alert.png" 
      end  

      marker.picture({:picture => "http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/     wp-content/uploads/mapicons/shape-default/color-3875d7/shapeco     lor-color/shadow-1/border-dark/symbolstyle-contrast/symbolshad     owstyle-dark/gradient-iphone/information.png",
                    :width => 32,
                    :height => 32})

      marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/businesses/info",   
        :locals => {:name => plot.name, :battery => @battery, :date => rand(6.months.ago..Time.now), :ip => @ip, :connected => @connected, :address1 => plot.address1, :city => plot.city })  
   end  
 end

  def load_businessz
   @businessz_default = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(Business.paginate(page: params[:page])) do |plot, marker|  
      marker.lat plot.latitude  
      marker.lng plot.longitude  

      @status = rand(1..4)  
      @battery = rand(10..90)  
      @ip = "192.168."+rand(0..255).to_s+"."+rand(15..250).to_s  
      @connected = rand(50..100)  

      if @status == 1  
        url_alert = "/assets/good.png"
        @status == "Normal"  
      else  
        url_alert = "/assets/alert.png" 
      end  

      marker.picture({:picture => "http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/     wp-content/uploads/mapicons/shape-default/color-3875d7/shapeco     lor-color/shadow-1/border-dark/symbolstyle-contrast/symbolshad     owstyle-dark/gradient-iphone/information.png",
                    :width => 32,
                    :height => 32})

      marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/businesses/infoz",   
        :locals => {:name => plot.name, :battery => @battery, :date => rand(6.months.ago..Time.now), :ip => @ip, :connected => @connected, :city => plot.city })  
   end  
 end



  private

  def set_business
      @business = Business.find(params[:id])
    end

  def mapping_params
    params.require(:business).permit(:name, :full_address, :address1, :city, :state, :zipcode, :latitude, :longitude)
  end

  def business_params
    params.require(:business).permit(:name, :city, :state, :zipcode, :address1, :address2, :category1_id, :category2_id, :category3_id, :category1, :category2, :category3, :phone, :website, :latitude, :longitude)
  end
  # added correct user admin user for business 4 29 18
  def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end

  #def logged_in_user
   # unless logged_in?
    #  store_location
     #   flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      #  redirect_to login_url
  #  end
  #end
end
```

Here is my search controller:

```
    class SearchController < ApplicationController



  def search
    if params[:term].nil?
      @businesses = []
    else
      @businesses = Article.search params[:term]
    end
  end 
end
```

My business infoz page for the marker window which works in the second example:

```
<b>Name:</b> <%= name %><br>
<b>City:</b> <%= city %><br>
```

Is there a way to just pass some data into that info window, unfortunately I've tried everything but can only pass strings.  Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41033156/4160532)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
When I search for items....my search controller returns @businesses.
Then @businesses is passed to my marker builder which is called load_businessz.
Then In my my Business controller I have a search method which returns @businesses and then at the bottom I have to run the method load_businessz, which only builds the markers for the items I searched for.  Then In my View file I pass the variable @businessz_default which is created by the method load_businessz.  Now it Google maps populates only the objects I search for.